# Blender Orbit Locks up

Tags: 3d-view

I am new at blender, and as I was orbiting w/ middle mouse button on my logitech mouse, releasing the middle mouse button didn't stop the orbit. The only way I could stop the display from orbiting with my cursor was pressing escape. After that, orbiting didn't work anymore, and I had to restart my mouse.

Any idea what's causing this?
Thanks

Comment: I just realized that it happens when I move my viewpoint under the grid. Any ideas?

Comment: Nvm, I realized how to fix it. Simply tilt the middle wheel in one direction or the other.

Comment: Glad you got it working :) I'm closing this question as it seems the problem was caused by the mouse itself